# How to Build Skia in Mac OS

Tags: skia

I'm beginner to Skia. So Just tried to build Skia in my machine ( macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 ).
I just followed the instructions [Build](https://skia.org/user/build).

- Downloaded depot_tools
- Downloaded Skia from git
- bin/gn gen out/Static --args='is_official_build=false'
- python2 tools/git-sync-deps
- ninja -C out/Static

i did these instructions. But my xcode (version 9.2) doesnt support -std=c++17 so i replaced with -std=c++1z in all places.
But it throws error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3RO0.png)

Please help to build skia for mac, and how to xcode project from this?

Answer (score 0):

> Skia makes use of C++17 language features (compiles with -std=c++17 flag) and thus requires a C++17 compatible compiler.

You'd better to update your xcode version.

> Mac users may want to pass --ide=xcode to bin/gn gen to generate an Xcode project

You can check this.[How to build skia](https://skia.org/docs/user/build/)